# What does it mean by "has tended" in the follwing sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality

I was searching for some examples of "To Make progress", I mean I wanted to know how to use "To Make Progress" in a sentence. I ended up finding a website with some examples. But I faced the below sentence:

> **This preoccupation has tended to make progress on other issues difficult**.

I actually didn't realize what this sentence is saying! I also don't know why it is using "has tended" because I didn't find any sample using "have" or "has" before the verb **tend** in **LongMan Dictioanary**!

Can I say: **This preoccupation has usually made making progress on other issues difficult** instead of the preceeding one?

Would anybody explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One definition of *tend* is 'be likely to behave in a particular way' - that is, 'have a tendency to...'.

The reason you haven't found *has tended* in your dictionary is that it's an ordinary past perfect tense.

Looking at your alternative version, I would suggest *frequently* rather than *usually*. *Made making* is clumsy, but you could simply leave out *making.*

Comment: You mean I can use "Making" anyway but it's better not to use it? Or I have to omit "Making" from my alternative version?

Comment: And I think the sentence says: That preoccupation led to difficulty. Am I right?

Comment: I _suggested_ that you leave out 'making' because it isn't necessary, and it's not very good style to use two forms of the same verb together. The sentence means that the preoccupation has frequently made it difficult for people to make progress on other issues. NB You _make progress_ when you are getting on well with a task, but this sentence uses _make_ in a different sense - it _causes progress to be difficult_.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks for your very useful explanation.